# View OLAP cube details in Excel

Tags: excel, olap, data-warehouse, pivot-table

Is there a way to view the details (the grain) in an OLAP cube in excel? I know excel can already show the measures that are aggregrated, but the users want to see the details... ie the individual grain. So, in my case, the fact table contains order information (order number, the dollar amount, etc). The measures are all aggregrated, but once the user sees an aggregration, they want to be able to see the details of that aggregration. Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doubleclicking the aggregate cell that you want to see the breakdown.

Comment: thats awesome! You saved me a lot of trouble. I have to make a drillthrough action to be able to do that, but thats ok. Do you know how to show non-dimensional or measure details in that drillthrough action?

Comment: Not sure about this, but I don't think that's available